# GCP Networking: Unexplained VPN tunnel egress usage spikes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've been trying to reconcile VPN total egress traffic usage with GCE instances mean sent bytes from monitoring metrics.

I'm faced with daily spikes in VPN usage that I'm not able to trace back to GCE instances or any other GCP services.

What can I be possibly missing ?

[image: See VPN Spikes VS. VM Sent Bytes Screenshot]

Cheers.

Comment: In my personal opinion and experience, I would suggest to reach out to [support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) since they may have some clues to help you with this

Comment: did just that. thx